# Writing a comparision function for qsort

Tags: c, structure, qsort

I'm writing a comparision function that compares and organizes names by ascending order of last name and if both last names are the same, descending order of first names. The function I have right now will not do that.

Here is the function:

```
int namecmp(const void *p, const void *q)
{
    const name *pp = p;
    const name *qq = q;
    int n;

    if((n = strcmp(pp->last, qq->last)) != 0)
        return n;

    return qq->first - pp->first;
}
```

I am trying to organize a dynamic array of structures, here are my structures.

```
typedef struct
{
char last[NAMESIZE];
char first[NAMESIZE];
}name;

typedef struct
{
int id;
name name;
float score;
}record;

typedef struct {
record *data; /* the dynamic array */
size_t nalloc; /* number of records allocated */
size_t nused; /* number of records in use */
} record_list;
```

and here is how qsort is called.

```
qsort(list->data, list->nused, sizeof(list->data[0]), namecmp);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I did what you suggested now i have the wrong output.

my output is:

```
3456789 Burns, Monty: 100.00
4567890 Simpson, Lisa: 95.00
1234567 Simpson, Homer: 35.50
6666666 Simpson, Bart: 45.00
2345678 Flanders, Ned: 99.50
```

EDIT 2:

How i store string into the structure.

```
            if(sscanf(line,"%s", lastname) == 1)
        {

            if(strlen(lastname) < NAMESIZE)
            {
                lastname[0] = toupper((int)lastname[0]);
                strcpy(rec->name.last, lastname);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: why do you think you need a strcmp for last name, but not first?

Answer (score 4):

You need to call strcmp on the first name as well or this will not work (as that's just subtracting addresses in memory). Change the last line to

```
return strcmp(pp->first, qq->first);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but now the function outputs in the wrong order somewhat

Comment: It should probably be `pp` before `qq` unless you want the first names sorted in a different order than the last names.

Comment: I would recommend using strcasecmp() to cope with differences in case.

Comment: The first way should have been correct, edited back to the original, also would case matter in this scenario?

Comment: Actually I think it is because of case. because in my program i use toupper on the first letter after it has been validated.

Comment: Well if the first letter is always uppercase then the comparison is fine, try strcasecmp() instead and see if that gives you what you want.

Comment: still gives me the same thing

Comment: This might be irrelevant but are you null terminating your strings correctly?

Comment: I've edited my original post to show how i store the name into the structure

Comment: I have no idea why it wouldn't work correctly based on that comparison function as I just wrote a stub program that sorts them correctly.

Comment: I've pasted my source code here 

http://pastebin.com/xJ7wfRN1

It must be how i stored the strings

Comment: I suggest you make 1 comparison function to use in qsort and have it take the structure that contains name, score and id. Having 2 separate sorting functions makes it hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: but the name is stored in another structure, does that mean i have to make Name name into Name *name?

Comment: I'm kind of confused by your code, are you using your own list implementation or using an array with realloc? Also you can just check record->name.first and record->name.last and send that to strcmp

Comment: I'm using an array with realloc

Comment: Ok then try what I recommended before and just write a comparison function for the structure you want to sort on this way it rules out any discrepancies.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison function has two comparisons (Edited one), but in different order. 
First has strcmp(p, q) and return statement has strcmp(q,p). Make them same, and it ll work !!

Shash